'Put token failed. status-code: 401, status-description: Invalidissuer: Token issuer is invalid' error when running Azure function in command line
I have an Azure project with an Azure function. It works fine in Visual Studio. However, when I run it in the command line using 'func start' on my machine, I get the continuous error '.... Put token failed. status-code: 401, status-description: Invalidissuer: Token issuer is invalid... '.
Some posts mentioned that it might be using another tenant id. I verified it's the correct tenant id with az login plus supplying the -t argument. I defined AZURE_TENANT_ID in local.settings.json. I suspect that from the command line, it's using a different credentials scheme or a different user. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this issue? To find out what's the current issuer it's using and what it should be using?
I have the latest Azure tools installed.

Firstly login to azure using az login then use az account set --subscription <subs-id> to set subcription, then it should work.

@RithwikBojja Same error

Run the command az ad signed-in-user show to check current logged in user.

Strange - I got exactly the same error, but for me, specifying "AZURE_TENANT_ID" or the connection-specific "<CONNECTION_NAME_PREFIX>__tenantId" in local.settings.json worked:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "<CONNECTION_NAME_PREFIX>__fullyQualifiedNamespace": "<NAMESPACE>.servicebus.windows.net",
    "<CONNECTION_NAME_PREFIX>__tenantId": "<tenantId>" // This line fixed the error for me
  }
}

Using connection-specific settings as opposed to "AZURE_*" is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference?tabs=blob&pivots=programming-language-csharp#azure-sdk-environment-variables
